# CP violation in the B-meson system

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, particle-accelerators

I was reading about historical measurements of CP violation and apparently, until the discovery of the top quark, one of the strongest CP violations was coming from the system of B-mesons.
I read that this could usually be tested by using an asymmetric e$^\pm$ accelerator with an invariant mass Y(4S), but I was trying to find out the reason of the asymmetry and also why the mass used was Y(4S).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Y(4S) is massive enough to decay into a pair of $B$ mesons. Because it’s a resonance, it has a large production cross-section: you get more events than you would at non-resonant energies.

That allows the experimenters to study the $B_{\rm{short}}$ and $B_{\rm{long}}$ mesons, the analog of the $K_{\rm{short}}$ and $K_{\rm{long}}$ where CP violation has been studied.

The asymmetric energy means that the Y(4S) is created in motion, hence the $B$ mesons are created in motion. By measuring how far they fly, the experimenters can measure how long they lived.

The [BaBar](http://www-public.slac.stanford.edu/babar/) and [Belle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belle_experiment) experiments worked this way. [This is an early BaBar pape](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0011024)r that discusses the physics and methods.

[image]